# How to align these two expressions, one has one more number?

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, phantom

I am trying to align `(-(a-1)^2-1)x+(-(a-1)^2-1)` and `(-(a-1)^2-1)x+1` using `\phantom` command. Since `(-(a-1)^2-1)x+1` is missing the `(-(a-1)^2-1)` part, I added `\phantom{(-(a-1)^2-1)}`, but there is an extra space that I am not sure from were it comes:

[image: MWE output]

I guess it comes from adding the "`1`", but I do not know how to compensate this extra space.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{array}{c}
     (-(a-1)^2-1)x+(-(a-1)^2-1)\\
     (-(a-1)^2-1)x+\phantom{(-(a-1)^2-1)}1
\end{array}\]

\end{document}
```

I want this output:

[image: Output that I want]

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to remove the `1` from the `\phantom`, since it shows up explicitly outside the `\phantom`.  I replace it with `{}` placeholder.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{array}{c}
     (-(a-1)^2-1)x+(-(a-1)^2-1)\\
     (-(a-1)^2-1)x+\phantom{(-(a-1)^2-{})}1
\end{array}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

In response to a comment from the OP, I leave this also, to show what can be done when the `\phantom` and residual term do not share common digits.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[\begin{array}{c}
     (-(a-1)^2-1)x+(-(a-1)^2-1)\\
     (-(a-1)^2-1)x+\phantom{(-(a-1)^2-1)}\mathllap{5-4+2^2}
\end{array}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it worked! A side question: what if the second line has e.g. `5-4+2^2` instead of `1`? There will be no more comparisons.

Comment: In that case, I would leave the original (complete) `\phantom` and then use the `mathtools` package to place a `\mathllap{5-4+2^2}`.  Please see edit.

Answer (score 2):

Add more alignment points:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{@{} l @{}>{{}}c<{{}}@{} r @{}}
     (-(a-1)^2-1)x &+& (-(a-1)^2-1)\\
     (-(a-1)^2-1)x &+& 1
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! You have manipulated `array` arguments when I only need it for this question, but it is a good approach. I will have to study your `array` parameters more carefully to understand it.